# Alternative future tense

Tags: word-choice

Teachers say we do not have to use "will" while we talking about the future event

I can't identify the differences of these expressions

1.I am going to buy a book.

2.I plan to buy a book.

3.I am about to buy a book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Will* talks about the future -correct. But then, there are many ways you can talk about the future without using *'will'* is also correct.

Your teacher just came up with three of those numerous ways to talk about the future.

> I am going to buy a book - [*going to* can be used for the future event.](http://www.yourdictionary.com/going-to) 
>  I plan to buy a book - the word '[plan](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/plan_1)' talks about the future. What you intent to do or achieve in future 
>  I am about to buy a book - *[about to](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/about_3)* talks about something you are going to do (in future) very soon.

It's interesting to know that you can also talk about the 'future' by using 'present continuous'. We often use PC to talk about the future events that are ***surely*** going to happen. Check this..

> The train ***is leaving*** by 2 pm (say..you are telling this to someone at 1;50 pm) 
>  The school ***is arranging*** an event this Sunday (future tense, but it's sure so it's okay to use the present continuous).

Comment: What would you think when a phone is ringing, and your relative say he is going to pick up the phone?

Comment: The same. going to here means in a very short time, he's picking up the phone. Of ofcourse a very near future